# I am trying to create a function called codechecker to determine a code is correct or not?

Tags: python-3.x

Not sure I am doing it right or not, I want to get True if I enter "ENG 123" and False "123ENG" or "ENG123". would some please help me. Thank you

```
      def CodeChecker(user_word)
          for number in range(1,2,3,4,6)
          course_code =input( ENG, COM, SCO, SCI)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have for this problem?  It's not clear in your question - how do you get '123'?  Should it be another input('please enter your course id: ')?  Please make it clear by showing the code you did and where's stuck.

Comment: I want to create a function which takes user input with 3 letters and 3 digits with a space in-between them.

Comment: Just check out the code snippet to see if that can  help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ezy, since the question is not very clear as you've stated, it's hard to guess how the user should enter two pieces of information to the program.

However, you can just this snippet and use it as template to start work out your final solution.  (Just try to run with different inputs)

```
COURSES = ['ENG', 'COM', 'SCO', 'SCI']
VALID_DIGITS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 6)   # Example

def CodeChecker():
    
    cid = input('please input your course id: (1, 2, 3, 4, 6) ')
    course = input('please enter your course: ')
    
    data = course+ ' ' + cid
    print(data)

    if data == 'ENG 123':
        return True
    else:
        return  False  # it's not a valid course + ID?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(CodeChecker())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I just want give only these digits. 12346

Comment: Could you read the code template and play with it to suite your needs?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. one more thing, just want to know how do I use dict() function in it, could you please give me one example?

Comment: Hi, @Ezy, there is no use of dict() in the code template. If you find this post is helpful, please accept and upvote it?    Let me know if you've worked out this...